# Is this the right way to use method "add"?

Tags: java

So my friend created a queue class which has an instance variable `size = 0;` and for the add method he uses.

But what will happen to index 0 in this case?

It will not have an elements declared to it since add starts from size++. Which is 1 starting position.

```
public void add(T data) {
    if(size > elements.length) {
        throw new QueueException("Queue is full");
    }
    elements[size++] = data;
}
```

Comment: I would recommend you try out what the result of `size++` is

Comment: `size++` it's post increment which means that `size` will be incremented by 1 after assignment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`size++` returns the `size` value before it gets incremented in the background. Because of that the `elements[0]` will be assigned. See [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) on incrementing.

The problem is with the last element. The code will attempt to assign `elements[elements.length]` which is above the array capacity. The guard should be:

```
if (size >= elements.length) {
  throw new QueueException("Queue is full");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didnt knew that the value gets incremented after it has been assigned.

Comment: @ZiadYounis - that's the difference between `++size` (pre-increment) and `size++` (post-increment).